# Replace a empty keys in array in a loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to get equal cloums for different arrays for list view. For example, I have posts in a list view, some of them have 5 values but some 3 or 4.

I want to replace all non-existing $keys=>$val[0] to "-".

And get table like this.

ID ; TITLE2 ; TITLE3 ; TITLE4 ; TITLE5

ROW1 ; ROW2 ; ROW3 ; ROW4 ; ROW5

ROW1 ; ROW2 ; ROW3 ; ROW4 ; ---------

ROW1 ; ROW2 ; ROW3 ; --------- ; ---------

ROW1 ; ROW2 ; ROW3 ; ROW4 ; ROW5

And after loop table is broken. Here is a code for getting a values from post_meta table.

```
foreach($meta_values as $key=>$val)
{

echo  '<td>'.$val[0].'</td>';

}
```

Comment: If I think what you're thinking then just use an inline conditional? - `($val[$x] == null ? '----' : $val[$x])`

Comment: It is absolutely unclear what you are trying to do. Post error which you have, full code what you use and make a more clear title.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to know max elements in row, for this you can count elements in header. Then you can interate through row and check for non-existing keys (empty($val[$i]) and change them to " ---------"

```
//If first element is header 
$length = count($meta_values[0]);

foreach($meta_values as $val) {
    foreach ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        if (empty($val[$i])) {
           $val[$i] = " ---------";
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Also $meta_value has lots of values what I don't need, I have used this condition to filter them in a loop `if (substr($key, 0, 1) != '_' && $key !== 'um_content_restriction')` but how can I do it know? **Count()** function will give me number of all keys in array included keys what I filtered.

Comment: @Hazzy then first you have to filter array and then do what I answered above